# Attaching a SQL Server database to a Docker container throws error- Docker for Windows

Tags: docker

I am using the below command in Powershell and Docker for Windows (Windows 10 Pro)

```
    docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=Infra_2017 -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -v 
    c:/infra_mvc_projects/SampleDb:c:/infra_mvc_projects/SampleDb -e 
    attach_dbs="[{'dbName':'AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Data','dbFiles':
```

['c:\infra_mvc_projects\SampleDb\AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Data.mdf','c:\infra
        mvc_projects\SampleDb\AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Log.ldf']}]" 
        microsoft/mssql-server-windows

**Below is the error**

```
    VERBOSE: Starting SQL Server

    docker : Sqlcmd: 'AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Data";CREATE DATABASE 
    "AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Data" ON (FILENAME = 
    N'c:\infra_mvc_projects\SampleDb\AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Data.mdf'),
    (FILENAME = 
    N'c:\infra_mvc_projects\SampleDb\AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Log.ldf') FOR 
    ATTACH ;"': Unexpected 
    argument. Enter '-?' for help.
    At line:1 char:1
    + docker logs 673
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Sqlcmd: 'Advent... '-?' for 
    help.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    VERBOSE: Changing SA login credentials
    VERBOSE: Attaching 1 database(s)
    VERBOSE: Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query sp_detach_db 
    "AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Data";CREATE
    DATABASE "AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Data" ON (FILENAME = 
    N'c:\infra_mvc_projects\SampleDb\AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Data.mdf'),
    (FILENAME = 
    N'c:\infra_mvc_projects\SampleDb\AdventureWorksDW2008R2_Log.ldf') FOR 
    ATTACH ;
    VERBOSE: Started SQL Server.
```

- The container gets created and able to open in Sql server management studio. But unable to attach the database with the above error.

Comment: I get the same error :-(

Answer (score 0):

Per the solution posted over in GitHub, the latest developer and express sqlserver images with setting the ATTACH_DBs environmental var works fine.